# RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'lid.B.L': Invalid middle control position: 2 Incorrect armature for type 'stretchy_chain'

Tags: error, rigify

I get this error after placing the face controls around my characters mesh and trying to generate a rig.

> RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'lid.B.L': Invalid middle control position: 2
> Incorrect armature for type 'stretchy_chain'

I have not added any bones inside the face rig and made sure all my joints are snapped together, I'm not sure what other requirement I'm not following.
I am not sure why it doesn't like the bone position, I suspect it's not even really about that bones' position, rather something else is the problem but it isn't clear from this error message.
 I googled this error and couldn't find anyone who had run into it.
Maybe someone on here knows ?

Comment: Have you pressed the *Upgrade Face Rig* button? Can you add a screenshot or share a file with the meta rig?

Comment: -have not added any bones: Good! 
-made sure all my joints are snapped together: Good!
But have you deleted any bones? Check if any bones of the lower lid have been deleted or unparented. (Consider uploading your metarig.)

Comment: Yes I pressed all the buttons before doing anything. I just started one version back and moved my joints again while regenerating every few manipulations to see which one would break it. Didn't break.
I suspect I moved a joint that was supposed to stay connected to its parent an unnoticeable amount but enough to cause the error. in Edit mode you can pull a child away from its parent if you don't select them both when moving.